# Is there a limit to how many WiFi networks can be stored?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

When you go to a new place and connect to a wifi android "remembers" it and connects automatically next time. Is there a limit to how many networks can be stored? I understand it is probably not limited to some specific number but still - what is an approximate count before phone starts act weird or something else bad happens?

Answer (score -1):

I think it is infinite because when you connect to a wifi, Android saves the wifi in wifi_supplicant file and when ever android finds the wifi having a name saved in this file. Android tries to connect with that wifi automatically.

Comment: yes, but still the number can't be really infinite. If you store 10000000000 networks in that file clearly something bad will happen (simply run out of space or smth else). I'm trying to figure out how much is too much.

Comment: If a person uses hisor her phone for lifetime. Then only I think he can use 100000000 wifi or more than that. And you know it is not possible. So if it happens android is smart enough that it will remove the wifi which are not used recently.

Comment: -1: this answer is speculation, not fact. Please add some research to it: while it is known that Android uses the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` to store network info, saying that infinite networks can be saved seems far-fetched.